# Google Sheets: {{campaign}}&' - 1' + {{campaign}}&' - 2' + {{campaign}}&' - 3'

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a sheet with rows that contain `campaignnames` and `values`. The problem is that some of the `campaignnames` have ' - 1', ' - 2', or ' - 3' appended to  the name.

I need a formula that will  trim the ' - 1', ' - 2', or ' - 3' from the `campaignames` and append the `values` to the trimmed `campaignames`.

For example `campaignnames` of `name01-3` and `value` of `20000` should result in a new `campaignnames` of `name012000`.

I have experimented with `vlookup()` and `sum()`, but not successful.

Comment: Hi, ricardo de Vries, the desired result of your Q is not clear to me.

Comment: I edited you your post, to try to clarify the question. Can you verify this is the question your are asking?

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is what I'm asking. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You've asked very specifically for a formula, which implies that though you are looking to create "new campaignnames", the questioner will handle the Copy/Paste Value aspect.

There are lots of options. SEARCH&LEFT was an obvious candidate, but I chose SPLIT because it naturally divides cell contents.

```
=index(split(A2:A4," - ",true),1,1)&B2
```

---

Here's a sample of the results
[image: Campaign Name rewrite]

---

As usual;)... it *might* (or not) be better if this was an ARRAYFORMULA. Despite my efforts, a cleverer person will no doubt conjure one up in a thrice.

---